# How loose coupling is achieved in Annotation based approach

Tags: xml, spring, annotations, loose-coupling

How loose coupling is achieved in annotation based approaches? Because if I want to make any changes in the bean, I have to make the changes in corresponding java class. So how can I say it is loosely coupled.

Comment: loose coupling between what and what ? what differences u make between "bean" and "java class" ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you first understand what loose coupling is. Please read or at least see the video of Uncle Bob Martin. I am sure you will get your answer and gain more.
Ref:

1. Uncle Bob SOLID principles - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zHiWqnTWsn4
2. Clean Code: https://www.amazon.in/Clean-Code-Robert-C-Martin/dp/8131773388